# Resolve unsigned long / pointer ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++11, redhat, rogue-wave

Our legacy code is using RogueWave library. I am trying to construct a RWTime object from a 0 literal. However, anything I do doesn't seem to have an effect and the compiler still have two constructors to select from:

```
error: call of overloaded 'RWTime(int)' is ambiguous
   _time(static_cast<unsigned long>(0))
                                      ^
note: candidates are:
RWTime::RWTime(const tm*, const RWZone&)
     RWTime(const struct tm* ptm, const RWZone& zone = RWZone::local());
     ^
RWTime::RWTime(long unsigned int)
     RWTime(unsigned long s)
     ^
constexpr RWTime::RWTime(const RWTime&)
 class RW_DEPRECATE_TYPE("Use RWDateTime instead") RW_TOOLS_SYMBOLIC RWTime
                                                                     ^
constexpr RWTime::RWTime(RWTime&&)
```

I would like to use the `unsigned long` constructor, but I don't seem to be able to actually pass unsigned long. I tried:

```
_time(static_cast<unsigned long>(0))
_time((unsigned long)0)
_time(0UL)
_time(0)
```

but no effect. Maybe the problem is that a pointer has `uintptr_t` type, which is synonymous to `size_t` type which is synonymous to `unsigned long`. And then there are actually two constructors taking `unsigned long`.

EDIT: I checked the RWTime class documentation and they mention the problem: "The compiler can parse 0 as either an integer or a pointer. Since there is also a constructor that takes a pointer (to `struct tm`), if you want to construct a time from the `unsigned long` value 0, you must be explicit:

```
RWTime earlyTime((unsigned long)0);
```

However, for some reason it doesn't work for me (using c++11).

Comment: The problem is not the pointer-integer ambiguity, at least not by itself. ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5723ad746c9c1d21))

Comment: A pointer does not have the type `uintptr_t`. `uintptr_t` isn't a pointer type, it's an integer type large enough to hold the value of any pointer when interpreted as an integer.

Comment: Hm I think it should compile.

Comment: Sounds like your compiler is bugged. Can you produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the same compilation failure in a self-contained example, without including RW or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was having a look at wrong piece of code after all.

```
_time(0UL)
```

works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use c11 you can't override your problem using nullptr and nullptr_t:
The compiler can choose between a pointer and a int function when value is 0 (or NULL that is 0 also).

You have to define a new function that accept nullptr_t for avoid ambiguous:

```
   RWTime::RWTime( std::nullptr_t np)
```

And, of course, use `std::nullptr` for null pointers

As you point that is not possible to change library code I propose a second solution:
Define an intermediate variable to give a clue to compiler which function must choose

```
    unsigned long tmp = 0;
    _time(tmp);
```

Another way can be give the second parameter:

```
     _time(0, RWZone::local());
```

Comment: RWTime is an external library, which I cannot modify

Comment: I guess that definining a intermediate variable can fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable to you, you could take out the default value for `RWZone` in the constructor:

```
RWTime(const struct tm* ptm, const RWZone& zone = RWZone::local());
```

So that it reads:

```
RWTime(const struct tm* ptm, const RWZone& zone);
```

Then the 0 cannot be taken for this because the `RWZone` argument would be missing.

Of course you could add a static method that allowed you to create a `RWTime` object that only takes a `const struct tm*` like so:

```
static RWTime create(const struct tm* ptm) { return RWTime(ptr, RWZone::local()); }
```

Comment: RWTime is an external library, which I cannot modify

Comment: Hmm, can you wrap it in another class? I guess this would depend on how often you use the `RWTime` class directly in your code.